# PHP query inactive minutes counting toward session timeout

Tags: php

There is much information available about how to detect if a PHP session has already expired. To quote from one of the many well-written articles:

> The session.gc_maxlifetime PHP.ini directive controls how long a session is allowed to exists before it is considered garbage and is cleaned up. Every call to the session_start() function has a chance to trigger the garbage collection routine. [Source](https://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/889606-setting-timeout-php-sessions)

**But is there any way to query where the inactivity timer is at?**

Sure, I can set up my own inactivity tracker, but since the server is already trackng that number, is there any way to check that?

Note: I seek a methodology that will work with a shared hosting CPANEL account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if this is what you are asking but it should be possible to:

1. Check the value of `session.gc_maxlifetime`
2. Check the [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) of the session file
3. Subtract Step #2 from the current timestamp and hopefully it's less than Step #1

The only issue with this is that if the session is read and not modified then the timestamp will remain the same unless you disable `session.lazy-write`.